# Каждый элемент импорта в отдельный файл gulp

Tags: gulp, сборка, stylus

Добрый день имею папку с файлами папка "file"
В ней файлы a.styl,b.styl,c.styl
Есть файл f.styl
Его содержание:

```
@import "file/a"
@import "file/b"
@import "file/c"
```

Вопрос: Как запрограммировать gulpfile.js чтобы он каждый файл а,b,c минифицировал в a.css b.css c.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    styl = require('gulp-stylus'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify');


var path = {
    build: {
        css: 'build/css/'
    },
    src: {
        style: 'src/style/*.styl'
    },
    watch: {
        style: 'src/style/*.styl'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(styl({'include css': true}))
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css));
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'style:build'
]);


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```